# Issue passing variable across class files

Tags: objective-c, xcode, class, variables

I am having difficulty passing variable from one class file to another. I have tried the Global Variable creator extern, but that also doesn't work.

Specifically, I am trying to pass a variable from a new class file I created called `NDSClassSiteViewController` to the master controller `NDSClassMasterViewController`.

I have added the @property into the .h file as follows:

```
@interface NDSClassSiteViewController : UITableViewController {

    NSArray *sitesMenu;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *siteid;

@end
```

And then the @synthesize into the .m file as follows:

```
#import "NDSClassSiteViewController.h"

#import "NDSClassMasterViewController.h"

@interface NDSClassSiteViewController () {
    NSMutableArray *_objects;
}
@end

@implementation NDSClassSiteViewController

@synthesize siteid;
```

I set the variable in the .m file as follows:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showMenu"]) {

        NSInteger row = [[self tableView].indexPathForSelectedRow row];

        //NSArray *appcell = [sitesMenu objectForKey:@"Table"];

        NSLog(@"AppCell %@", sitesMenu);

        NSDictionary *entry = [sitesMenu objectAtIndex:row];

        self.siteid = [entry objectForKey:@"SITEID"];

        NSLog(@" sample SiteView %@", siteid);



        //NDSClassMasterViewController *detailController = segue.destinationViewController;
        //detailController.detailItemTwo = siteid;
    }
}
```

Then I try and access it in the Master View controller using the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    globalid = siteid;


}
```

But I get an error: `use of undeclared identifier siteid`

I don't really know why it won't allow me to use the variable? Am I missing something?

Comment: You're not using any variables.  I see only declarations of class-level properties and private iVars.

Comment: You declared it as part of the site VC, but you're saying you're trying to access it from the master VC. Is that right or a typo in your question?

Comment: Thats right, I created a new class file call SiteViewController and I am trying to access a variable from there in the MasterViewController.

Comment: Show us the declaration and implementation for the master view controller then!

Comment: The only thing I do in the MasterViewController is #import "NDSClassSiteViewController.h";

Answer (score 1):

You've declared a property on `NDSClassSiteViewController`. To access the property you need an instance of an `NDSClassSiteViewController` within scope, and you also must access it using the syntax for properties - either dot syntax or standard method call syntax.

To read the property:

```
aSiteViewController.siteID
[aSiteViewController siteID]
```

To set it:

```
aSiteViewController.siteID = @"Site ID here";
[aSiteViewController setSiteID:@"Site ID Here"]
```

When you are in a method of `NDSClassSiteViewController` then `self` points to the instance you likely want to use. Otherwise, you'll probably either create it in the method or have it passed in as a parameter. Also, when you are in an instance method of `NDSClassSiteViewController` you can access the instance variable that backs the property directly - usually this would be `_siteID` but you manually synthesized so just `siteID` should work. *Note that I did `siteID` instead of the `siteid` you're using. I did this for readability and to follow established Objective-C naming conventions.*

Comment: Thanks for the help! I managed to change the variable on Master View Controller from the SiteViewController using NDSClassMasterViewController *detailControllerTwo = segue.destinationViewController;
        detailControllerTwo.globalid = siteid;